# How to efficiently find spikes in 2D data projected to 1 axis

Tags: density-estimation, fourier-transform

I have the following points:[image]

My goal is to find the be able to differentiate the yellow points from the purple ones.

We can assume that the yellow points are aligned on the vertical axis.
We cannot tell anything from the purple points, we need to consider them as 'noise' of sort. They might appear in some parts, and even look kind of structured but nothing that we can know beforehand.

My idea was to project them all onto the horizontal axis, then use some kind of density estimation to detect 'spikes', but it seems overkill.

Also, if we assume that the 'lines' are separated by the same distance, does it helps? How could I use a Fourier transform to detect this gap? Or should I use something else?

Thank you !

EDIT:
Clarification on purple points.
Also, a simpler question might be: How can I find the x-coordinates of each yellow line?

Comment: Could you tell us more specifically and completely how the distribution of the yellow points might differ from that of the purple ones?  For instance, in your illustration it looks like the distribution of the yellow $y$ coordinates might be uniform, whereas that of the purple $y$ coordinate depends on the $x$ coordinate.  If so, this provides information to improve the classification of the points.

Comment: Done, thank you